# Dividing per a lower number

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sh

A shell script is giving me a trouble. It should display some increasing values each iteration. Dividing "1/9" is the source of the problem, and setting count as "1.0" should do the trick but gives me an error instead: 'Illegal number: 1.0'

```
count=1
rtime=9

until [ $count -eq $rtime ]
do
  echo $((($count/$rtime)*10))
  sleep 1
  count=$(($count+1))
done
```

Comment: given the integer arithmetic restriction, multiplying first help? `$(( 10*count/rtime ))` -- note, dollar signs are optional in arithmetic expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set -o nounset                              # Treat unset variables as an error
count=1
rtime=9

until [ $count -eq $rtime ]
do
    echo $(echo "scale=2; $((count*10))/$rtime" | bc)                                                                                 
    sleep 1
    count=$((count+1))
done
```

Comment: Add some description... ;-)

Comment: Useless uses of `echo` and subshells here! `bc <<< "scale=2; $count*10/$rtime"` would do the same thing more efficiently.

Comment: Thanks but I was needing echo to replace the current line each time; my real code is now is:
echo -n $lol "\r["$(echo "scale=2; $((count*100))/$rtime" | bc)"%]"

Answer (score 0):

The shell can only do integer arithmetics. For floats, you can try `bc`.

Comment: I have already tried, but it doesn't work
On top of that, on the real code I have extracted this extract, there is some string inside the "echo" :s

Hey, moreover, you're wrong, try echo $((1.0/4.0)) you'll see that we can do floats arithmetics. But I can't do that here.

Comment: @sidney: Replace the `echo` line with the following: `bc -l <<< '"string: ";'"($count/$rtime)*10"`